# jquery make date from integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need of making a program which can convert an integer number into a date using javascript/jquery. WhatI am thinking is to divide the numbers by 10 and then split them so then, depending upon the numbers I want to display the date in another input field.

The input given by the user should be like this:

910111

and the output should be

11/jan/1991

My code is:

```
    <input type="text" id="id1"/>
    <input type="text" id="id2" />

$("#id1").change('input', function(){
var input = $(this).val();
var remainder = [10]; 
var quotient = 0;
var divisor = 10;
var dividend = input;
var j=0;

var array1 = [10]; 

while(dividend >= 10)
{
    remainder[j] = dividend % divisor;
    quotient = dividend / divisor;
    dividend = quotient;
    j++;
}
});
```

The Updated code after the discussion is as follows which is not working when I pass the variable "input" instead of a hard coded value.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>
            Inzamam Tahir
    </title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var input = $("#id1").val();
            $("#id1").change(function () {
                var date = moment(input).format('DD/MM/YY');
                $("#id2").val(date);
            });
        });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type= "text" id = "id1"/>
<input type = "text" id = "id2"/>   
<input type = "submit" id = "id3"/> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An update to this question of mine: It worked when I placed var input = $("#id1").val(); below $("#id1").change(function () {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect Moment.js and use this snippet:

```
moment("910111", "YYMMDD").format('DD/MMMM/YYYY'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/400abej7/

Parse date: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Print (parsed) date: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your answer was very precise and very short and that really helped but right now I am trying to pass the variable into the code instead of passing a hard coded date but it is not working

Comment: I am now going to update my code above to let you know about that.

Comment: `moment(your_string_variable, format_variable)` - here you parse `your_string_variable` with defined format. Check moment.js example for more samples.

Answer (score 0):

best to assume 4 digit years, or you will have problems when you cross the 2000 boundary, but you can do this really simply with with modulus and divide. Much faster that most other solutions (looping or regEx etc):

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

$("#id1").change('input', function () {
    var input = ~~$(this).val()
    var year = ~~(input / 10000);
    var month = ~~(input % 10000 / 100);
    var day = ~~(input %100)
    var date = "" + day +"/" +months[month-1]+ "/" + year 
    alert(date);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/na46owxu/2/

**Notes:**

- `~~` is a shortcut integer conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array for months. And then you could do this

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
var input = "910111";
var output = input.replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/, function(m, g1, g2, g3){
   return g3 + "/" + (months[g2-1]) + "/19" + g1;
});
```